# ngresource custom method with web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ngresource

Cannot able to pass the custom object using ngresource.getting null value in web api.

```
 app.factory("Entry", function ($resource) {
                return $resource("/api/Emp/",
                    { },
                    {

                        "putmethod1": { 'url': '/TestEmployee', 'method': 'GET', 'params': { employee: '@employee' } }

                    }
                );
            });




postData = {
                    "id": 1,
                    "Empname": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
                    "Address": "Douglas Adams"
                };

     var ent = Entry.putmethod1({ employee: postData });
```

### Web api

```
    [Route("TestEmployee")]
    public IHttpActionResult GETEmployee1(Employee employee)
    {
    }
```

Employee object is null. please let me know where am going wrong?